# net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error in laravel echo with redis driver

Tags: laravel, redis, socket.io, laravel-5.3, laravel-echo

I'm using laravel-echo with redis driver to broadcast notifications. It works perfectly on my local system. But on my server, I'm getting `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` error. Browser console displays `http://ex.example.com:6001/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`.

I have not any knowledge about socket and redis. So I just have followed instruction of [laravel official doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/broadcasting#driver-prerequisites) and [laravel-echo-server](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server). and made just one change from [here](https://github.com/laravel/docs/issues/3173#issuecomment-284708455). But with help of that change, I'm able to let execute remaining js script. Issue of socket.io.js is still unsolved (Also in [github](https://github.com/laravel/docs/issues/3173)).

Here is steps which I have followed.

1. Follow [Laravel Official Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/broadcasting)
2. Install [Redis-Server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-redis-on-ubuntu-16-04)
3. Install [laravel-echo-server](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server)
4. Install [socket.io-clent](https://socket.io/docs/) in my project

**js**

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"
window.io = require('socket.io-client');    //suggested in github issue
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ':6001'
});
```

**laravel-echo-server.json**

```
{
    "authHost": "http://ex.example.com",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [
            {
                    "appId": "edbf10287972d875",
                    "key": "96403c9f93e1a2d86185e2d21aa0fae1"
            }
    ],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
            "redis": {},
            "sqlite": {
                    "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
            }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": ""
}
```

If anyone knows the solution, it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may sound simple, but did you check the firewall settings on your server?

edit: thanks to @AkshayVaghasiya for sharing the instructions for setting up your firewall correctly [[read here]](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Comment: For other users, I have followed instructions from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Comment: u saved me this instruction @AkshayVaghasiya. To people who have the same problem the comment is "here" is the answer